# contact form help needed php

Tags: php

I am working on the contact form on a webpage. The HTML and CSS is complete, how it supposed to be. However, now I need to make this button work so it sends an e-mail to the given e-mail address. I am a newbie in PHP, so hope someone could help me out.

HTML code:

```
<div id="thirdColumn">
<div id="contactOns">
      <form action="send.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain" class="form">  

        <p class="name">  
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="NAAM" />  
        </p>  

        <p class="email">  
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL" />   
        </p>  

        <p class="text">  
            <textarea name="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="BERICHT"></textarea>  
        </p>  

        <p class="submit">  
        <input type="submit" id="sent" value="VERSTUUR" />  
        </p>  
    </form>                         
</div> <!-- End contactOns -->
</div> <!-- End thirdColumn -->
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$mail_to = 'riksterrr@gmailc.com';
$subject = 'Bericht van een bezoeker '.$name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$message;

$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: Get rid of `$mail_status = ` since `$mail_status` is not being called, it'll just sit there. Also get rid of `enctype="text/plain"` that won't send your form at all. Do that and your form should now work.

Comment: What error are you getting? Do you have a mail server installed?

Comment: @Fred-ii- `$mail_status` will receive a response from `mail`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Got rid of both, but still not working. I do not have a mail server installed yet I think as the site is not up and running, just want to test whether the code is working.

Comment: @RikdeCort It worked for me, however your `$message` is not getting through. Also, check if you entered your Gmail correctly, you have this `riksterrr@gmailc.com` in your form. Notice the `c` after `gmail`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I keep getting an error, even if I change my e-mail address. Where do you test this ? I have nothing uploaded yet, I'm just running a preview in Coda 2. Could that be the problem?

Comment: "I do not have a mail server installed" problem identified. Install a mail server an it should work

Comment: @RikdeCort I figured out why `$message` is not coming through. Your comment box is `name="text"` and should be `type="text"`

Comment: @RikdeCort That is definitely the problem. You should have a server running with `mail()` otherwise it won't work.

Comment: @relentless I am trying to send the e-mail to my gmail and that one is set up on my macbook. However, not sure this is the mail server you are referring to.

Comment: @RikdeCort Unless you have PHP installed on your MAC book, you can't send out mail. A "Web server" does that, which looks like you don't have one setup. That, or find a free hosting service with `mail()` function available.

Comment: @RikdeCort So 2 things that needed to be changed in your HTML form are, get rid of `enctype="text/plain"` and change `<textarea name="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="BERICHT"></textarea>` to `<textarea type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="BERICHT"></textarea>`, then setup a server with `mail()`. Once that's all done, you'll be well on your way to success ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Okay have changed those two things in my html code, now I am looking for a Web Server. You were talking about installing PHP on my macbook ? Is this recommended ?

Comment: Thanks a lot tho for the comments so far, both of you!

Comment: @RikdeCort You're welcome. Installing PHP on your own MAC book is entirely up to you. However, if you haven't any experience in that field, I would then recommend not to; it can be a complicated/complex process.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have no experience in that, so I will stay away from that for now.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Okay thanks, I have just signed up, however can't seem to find the required information to set everything up and im not familiar with this website. Could you help me ? Sorry for asking, appreciate it a lot

Comment: @RikdeCort They'll send you the information that you need via Email once you gotten the confirmation Email. You'll get FTP login etc. then get an FTP client to upload the files or use their file manager, then upload into `public_html` folder or create sub-folders inside the `public_html` folder.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Is there any way I am able to contact you by mail, want to ask you for some help.. I am not able to chat with you yet due to low reputation.

Comment: @RikdeCort Sorry, I won't post my Email here publicly. What type of help is it that you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things that needed to be changed in your HTML form are, get rid of `enctype="text/plain"`

and change:

```
<textarea name="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="BERICHT"></textarea>
```

to:

```
<textarea type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="BERICHT"></textarea>
```

You had `name="text"` which should be `type="text"`

Since you do not have your own Web server setup with PHP, you will need to find a hosting company that has `mail()` available in order to run your code properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Appreciate it. Will wait until I receive further information.

Comment: @RikdeCort I will delete a few of my comments, since you have the info. We should have went into chat for that, but that's all passed now.